# Regex for a number followed by a word

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

In JavaScript, what would be the regular expression for a number followed by a word? I need to catch the number AND the word and replace them both after some calculation.

Here are the conditions in a form of example:

```
123 dollars => Catch the '123' and the 'dollars'.
foo bar 0.2 dollars => 0.2 and dollars
foo bar.5 dollar => 5 and dollar (notice the dot before 5)
foo bar.5.6 dollar => 5.6 and dollar
foo bar.5.6.7 dollar => skip (could be only 0 or 1 dot)
foo bar5 dollar => skip
foo bar 5dollar => 5 and dollar
5dollar => 5 and dollar
foo bar5dollar => skip
```

- Of course 123.555, 0.365, 5454.1 are numbers too.
- For making things simpler the word is a specific one (e.g
  dollar|euro|yen).
- OK.. Thank you all... Here is the basic function I made so far:

  var text = "foo bar 15 dollars. bla bla..";
  var currencies = {
      dollars: 0.795
  };

  document.write(text.replace(/\b((?:\d+.)?\d+) *([a-zA-Z]+)/, function(a,b,c){
      return currencies[c] ? b * currencies[c] + ' euros' : a;
      }
  ));

Comment: I believe a regular expression for this might be somewhat complex and hard to debug. Have you tried custom parsing?

Comment: I'm new to regular expressions.. Although I do understand the basics this is obviously a complex one.

Comment: This isn't actually that much of a complicated regex expression - take something like a regex that matches every single RFC-valid email address, and doesn't match anything else. They can be thousands of characters long: http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php

Comment: You can use [regexpal](http://www.regexpal.com/) to check your regexp. Put the text at the lower window and put your regexp at the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
/\b(\d*\.?\d+) *([a-zA-Z]+)/
```

That will also match stuff like `.5 tests`. If you don't want that, use this:

```
/\b((?:\d+\.)?\d+) *([a-zA-Z]+)/
```

And to avoid matching "5.5.5 dollars":

```
/(?:[^\d]\.| |^)((?:\d+\.)?\d+) *([a-zA-Z]+)/
```

Comment: Hang on, did you want the word to be "dollar", or any word? If you wanted it to be "dollar", replace `([a-zA-Z]+)`) with `dollar`.

Comment: can I replace it with dollar|euro ?

Comment: `(dollars?|euros?)` would match and capture dollar/dollars/euro/euros

Comment: Yup, what @agreco said would work perfectly: `/\b(\d*\.?\d+) *(dollars?|euros?)/`

Comment: Almost ;).. Fails on foo bar 5.5.5 dollar and without the spaces

Comment: That's pretty complicated, and would result in falses on stuff like this: "I bought 5.5.5 dollars!" (typo; would be "I bought 5." followed by the price)

Comment: Okay, try the third regex I just added to avoid matching that.

Comment: OK.. Thank you all... Here is the basic function I made so far:
var text = "foo bar 15 dollars. bla bla..";
    
document.write(text.replace(/\b((?:\d+\.)?\d+) *([a-zA-Z]+)/,
function(a,b,c){
    switch(c)
    {
        case "dollars":
            return b*0.7950+" euros";
            break;
        default:
            return a;
    };
}
                            )
               );​

Comment: Don't use a switch for that! Switches are fairly bad practice in any situation, but in this case, it is better to use an object anyway: https://gist.github.com/3558982

Answer (score 1):

quick try:

```
text.match( /\b(\d+\.?\d*)\s*(dollars?)/ );
```

if you want to do dollar/dollars and euro/euros then:

```
text.match( /\b(\d+\.?\d*)\s*(dollars?|euros?)/ );
```

also `\s` would match all whitespace including tabs.. if you just want spaces then just put a space instead (like the other answer):

```
text.match( /\b(\d+\.?\d*) *(dollars?|euros?)/ );
```

Comment: "foo bar5 dollar => skip" - you should add a space before

Answer (score 0):

```
string.replace(/\d+(?=\s*(\w+))/, function(match) {
    return 'your replace';
});
```

Comment: Why are you using a function? You almost never need a callback, as you can refer to the matches in the replacement string.

Comment: @CallumMacrae Yes you can, but if he wants to check what's the match and then replace, how he will do it ?