# Positive lookbehind, followed by comma separated list, followed by positive lookahead

Tags: python, regex

Need to parse the output of the pytest log, specifically this line of it:

```
=========== 1 passed, 24 skipped, 75 deselected in 251.82s (0:04:11) ===========
```

What I have so far:

```
r"(?<== ).+(?= in .+ =)"
```

Which gives the following output:

```
['1 passed, 24 skipped, 75 deselected']
```

Desired output is:

```
[('1', 'passed'), ('24', 'skipped'), ('75', 'deselected')]
```

I understand I can take my existing output and modify it with string modifications using methods like `str.split`, but I know it's doable in one regex. I just can't figure it out.

EDIT: To clear up some confusion. The real log file is very large and thus why I had the look-ahead and look-behind in my original solution. I wanted to make sure that only the line in the example I provided is captured.
Furthermore, the line won't always contain `passed, skipped, and deselected`. There are a lot more categories and the line can have all of them or just one of them (e.g. `2 passed in 25s` or `1 passed, 2 skipped, 3 failed, 4 deselected in 500s`, etc.)

Snippet from log file:

```
10:50:55  ============================= test session starts ==============================
10:50:55  platform linux -- Python 3.8.17, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.11.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /usr/local/bin/python
10:50:55  cachedir: .pytest_cache
10:50:55  plugins: lazy-fixture-0.6.3, mock-3.6.1, order-1.1.0, timeout-2.1.0, timeouts-1.2.1
10:50:55  timeout: 7200.0s
10:50:55  timeout method: thread
10:50:55  timeout func_only: False
10:50:55  setup timeout: 0.0s, execution timeout: 0.0s, teardown timeout: 0.0s
10:50:55  collecting ... collected 25 items
10:50:55  
10:50:55  tests/e2e/test_0_testbed_create.py::test SKIPPED
10:50:55  =========================== short test summary info ============================
10:50:55  PASSED tests/e2e/test_0_testbed_create.py::test
10:50:55  ======================== 1 passed, 24 skipped in 27.02s ========================
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex for a number followed by a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12221637/regex-for-a-number-followed-by-a-word)

Comment: `re.findall()` works very nice in this particular situation: `re.findall(r'`[`\b(\d+) (\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/uLaX5w/2)`', log)`.

Comment: @InSync unfortunately that won't work. The log file is filled with a lot of text. I just tried your solution and it captured `25 items` in this line: `collecting ... collected 25 items`. This is why I had the lookbehind and lookahead.

Comment: Then you should have provided something looks more like the real file instead of just one line. Please edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: @InSync added a snippet and clarified the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short and simple:

```
\b(\d+) ([A-Za-z]+)\b   # Match a number followed by a word
(?=.*=+$)               # but only if that same line ends with a series of '='.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/uLaX5w/4).

From my limited experience with `pytest`, I dare say that the probability of it emitting something that looks like `12 foo_ ====` is quite low. Thait said, this should be sufficient in most, if not all, cases.

Conveniently, `re.findall()` returns a list of tuples of groups for patterns which have capturing groups:

```py
print(re.findall(r'(\d+) ([A-Za-z]+)', log))
# [('1', 'passed'), ('24', 'skipped'), ('75', 'deselected')]
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I agree with you that just the look-ahead _should_ be enough, but I'm curious if it's possible to have the look-behind as well? I tried playing around with your regex to add it, but didn't have much luck.

Comment: @Mo2 No, since Python supports neither `\K`/`\G` nor non-fixed width lookbehind. If you want to use that, you will have to rely on the third-party module [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/).